# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpleaudio' but simpleaudio is installed

Tags: python, module, package

```
C:\Users\pscll\OneDrive\Jaar2\Python\Eindopdracht\CSD2\python_basics>pip install simpleaudio
Requirement already satisfied: simpleaudio in c:\users\pscll\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (1.0.4)

C:\Users\pscll\OneDrive\Jaar2\Python\Eindopdracht\CSD2\python_basics>python3 5_eindopdracht.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pscll\OneDrive\Jaar2\Python\Eindopdracht\CSD2\python_basics\5_eindopdracht.py", line 2, in <module>
    import simpleaudio as sa
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simpleaudio'**
```

So this one I find interesting. I had been working with simpleaudio just fine, but I've ran into a new issue.

As a complete newbie I find it hilarious that it tells me it cant find the module simpleaudio, but when attempting to install simpleaudio it tells me it already exists.

I've tried to troubleshoot this quite a bit already but I haven't been able to get anywhere at all. Any advice?

I've tried reinstalling python3 and simpleaudio entirely, using different versions like pip install and pip3 install.

I hoped it would work but it threw the same error.

Comment: Can you post the pythong version when using `python3 --version`? Maybe your python3 executable is not looking into the same directory your pip is installing to (3.12).

Comment: You seem to be onto something. Python3 --version returns python 3.11, while python --version returns python 3.12.
Edit: I had a LOT of issues with the versioning and haven't managed to fix it at all. I thought I had the default set to 3.12 but apparently not for python3.. The issue is that I can't find 3.11 absolutely anywhere. I don't get why it's still referring to an older version that I uninstalled way ago.